# Discord бот не выводит логи сообщения пользователя (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот код с которым у меня возникли проблемы:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(1085938113420988506)
    if message.author != client.user:
        await channel.send(f'{message.author} в "{message.channel}": {message.content or "пустое сообщение"}')
```

Этот код просто выводит: `"ник" в "канал":` и всё. Но после того как я немного модифицировал конец строки из `{message.content}` в `{message.content or "пустое сообщение"}`, то код начал выводить: `"ник" в "канал": пустое сообщение`.

Я пробовал это выводить через `print()` консоль - итог тот же. Пытался еще взять кусок кода, который берёт информацию введенную пользователем и сохраняет в отдельную переменную, но там буквально тоже самое, что и у меня.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно официальной документации:

> **message.content** - The actual contents of the message. If **Intents.message_content** is not enabled this will always be an empty string unless the bot is mentioned or the message is a direct message.

Проверяй эти условия.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(1085938113420988506)
    if message.author != client.user:
        await channel.send(f'{message.author} в "{message.channel}": {message.content or "пустое сообщение"}')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже решил свою проблему. Я просто почему-то не могу пометить вопрос как "завершенный".
Кстати, одних строк `intents = discord.Intents.default()` и `intents.message_content = True`, не достаточно. Нужно еще зайти в настройки бота и включить функцию "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT", для записи текста из сообщений пользователей и публикации его в закрытом канале.

Comment: Всё верно, галочку нужно, совсем забыл, довольно давно сталкивался с этой же проблемой.
Рад, что всё разрешилось